# Date difference in mySQL by certain number of days

Tags: mysql

There is a field `due_date` in my table. I want to get the records whose due_date is certain days ahead of today, i.e, the difference of `due_date` and `CURDATE()` can range between `-1` to `7` *(in days)*.

P.S.: `-1` denotes that `due_date` was yesterday.

> `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (due_date - CURDATE() = 7);`

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: This syntax is not  working

Comment: give me you table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query and this will fix  your problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM  TABLENAME 
WHERE due_date >= DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
AND due_date <= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Comment: But it won't work for `-1`, i.e., `due_date` was `yesterday`

Comment: let me fix this

Comment: Use this : DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY) with first compare date

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation`

Comment: I tried this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(due_date- CURDATE() >= -1) AND DATEDIFF(due_date- CURDATE() <8)`

Comment: You are doing it wrong. The function is: `DATEDIFF(date1, date2)`.
Try it:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) >= -1 AND DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) <8`

Comment: It says: `Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION tablename.date_diff does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(due_date, NOW()) <= 7 and DATEDIFF(due_date, NOW()) >= -1;
```

Comment: It says: `Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION tablename.date_diff does not exist`

Comment: change table  to your table name.